# How do i draw a box around my data in golang and print it?

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a table in my terminal to easily view the data I am using in my program. I can do this with fmt package but it is not as eloquent as I would like.

Comment: A standard library option: [text/tabwriter](https://golang.org/pkg/text/tabwriter/) can print data in a table-like, tab aligned way but it does so without drawing any borders.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/da0x/olog

It looks like this:

```
┌────────────┬─────┬────────┐
│ Name       │ Age │ Score  │
├────────────┼─────┼────────┤
│ John Smith │ 30  │ 99.223 │
│ Jane Smith │ 30  │ 99.223 │
└────────────┴─────┴────────┘
```